# how to convert observable data to lowercase in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

## Detail

I want to convert observable data in to lowerCase below is my code. I want to convert Value to lowercase

## Code

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: "search"
})

export class SearchPipe {

    transform(value, term) {
        console.log(term.toLowerCase());
        if (term == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.filter((item) => {
            return item.Email.includes(term) || item.FirstName.includes(term) || item.LastName.includes(term);
        });
    }

}
```

## image

[image]

Comment: isn't value.toLowerCase() working?

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: Can you tell me what is the data in value?

Comment: I attach the image already

Comment: I meant after you transform what the value!

Comment: it is a search pipe when I search 'Ahmed' is return value 'Ahmed' and if I search 'ahmed' it is not showing the result as expected

Comment: better to put this code in http://embed.plnkr.co/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU/ and I will try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Detail

I tried this.It works

## Code

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: "search"
})

export class SearchPipe {

    transform(value, term) {
        console.log(value);
        if (term == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.filter((item) => {
            return item.Email.toLowerCase().includes(term) || item.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(term) || item.LastName.toLowerCase().includes(term);
        });
    }
}
```